# How to return two or more strings in java?

Tags: java, string, return, return-value

How to return two or more string in java? I have tried the following code but I got no idea what the correct syntax is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class cat{
    public String description() {
        String color;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter breed: ");
        String breed= sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter color");
        color= sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("color is "+ color);
        return new String[] {breed, color};

            }

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    cat cat1= new cat();

                System.out.println("breed is: " + cat1.description());
                System.out.println("color is: "+ cat1.description());

}
}
```

Comment: You’d return an array or a tuple or whatever, but the return value needs to match the method signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create String attributes for your "cat" class.

```
public class Cat {
    private String breed;
    private String color;

    public Cat(String breed, String color) {
        this.breed = breed;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return this.breed;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }
}
```

Now you can access the getBreed() and getColor() methods in your main method.

It seems you just started out with oop. Maybe you should read a bit about the basics.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Yes, I just started out with oop.